# How much Mathematical Knowledge do most people on Mathematics Stack Exchange have?

Tags: discussion

How much Mathematical Knowledge do most people on Mathematics Stack Exchange have in terms of experience, and highest level of education (High school, College, Post-Graduate)

How can I get better at solving problems on this site (I'm a 9th grader who has taken the AP Calculus AB Exam)?

(Sorry if my wording is confusing)

Comment: This isn't really a problem solving site. Some people know commutative algebra and category theory, some only know linear algebra and probability.

Comment: People ask questions on this site ranging from high school arithmetic to advanced undergraduate/preliminary graduate topics. This site is not a good measure of one's skill. Personally, I answer occasional questions because I think I can give a good presentation of an important concept, or there's a problem I find interesting. Neither of those reflect on me.

Comment: Personally, I know roughly $0.00001\%$ of all known mathematics. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I am an undergraduate mathematics major. As you can see, I haven't answered (or even asked) many questions on this site. Most of the questions that I can answer get closed before I can answer them.

However, I don't think I am a typical MSE user. Judging by the sophistication of the questions on this site, I would guess that most MSE users are either graduate students or professional research mathematicians. But I could be totally wrong. There are a fair amount of questions from high schoolers or undergraduates as well.

Congratulations on taking calculus as a high school freshman! If you follow the calculus tag, you may find some questions that you can answer. However, most of the questions on this site are probably well above your current level. If you really want to be able to answer questions on MSE, then you've got a lot of studying to do.

May I recommend some resources to get you started (in no particular order):

- [Paul's Online Math Notes](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/)
- [Mathematical Thinking: Problem Solving and Proofs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130144126) by D'Angelo and West
- [Algebra: Abstract and Concrete](http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/%7Egoodman/algebrabook.dir/book.2.6.pdf) by Frederick M. Goodman
- [Introduction to Real Analysis](https://sciencemathematicseducation.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/0471433314realanalysis4.pdf) by Bartle and Sherbert
- [Complex Variables and Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0073383171) by Brown and Churchill
- [Linear Algebra and it's Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0030105676) by Gilbert Strang
- [Introduction to Mathematical Statistics](https://minerva.it.manchester.ac.uk/%7Esaralees/statbook2.pdf) by Craig, Hogg, and McKean

Comment: most people here are undergrads and grad students, with overflow consisting of more advanced mathematicians.

Comment: A fairly large sector encompassed by "more advanced mathematicians", @DonThousand.  But you are absolutely correct: it is a mix-match.